# Power function expansion when the exponent is a function of integer

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I considering the following expansion of power function shown [here](https://www.math24.net/power-series-expansions/).

$$
{a^x} = 1 + {\large\frac{{x\ln a}}{{1!}}\normalsize} +\;{\large\frac{{{{\left( {x\ln a} \right)}^2}}}{{2!}}\normalsize} + {\large\frac{{{{\left( {x\ln a} \right)}^3}}}{{3!}}\normalsize} + \ldots +\;{\large\frac{{{{\left( {x\ln a} \right)}^n}}}{{n!}}\normalsize} + \ldots
$$

Here, $x, a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. Is there a way to simplify the expansion more when $x  \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$?

Comment: Not really. When $a=e$ and $x=1$ this is the series expansion for $e$.

Comment: If $x$ is a positive integer, $a^x$ is the best way to represent the function, IMO